# Использование минимального количества операторов при прохождении массива

Tags: php, массивы, оптимизация

имеется массив из четырех элементов

```
$arr = array('1name','4aaaaa','5smthn','3else');
```

необходимо, используя минимально возможное(это важно) количество операторов, пройти по массиву, и если элемент начинается на единицу, вывести сообщение, если на четверку, то сам элемент, если не на единицу, не на четверку, и не на тройку, то вывести какое то еще сообщение

главная суть задачи в том, чтоб использовать минимум всяких `if` и `==`
использование `substr()` так же нежелательно

Comment: а если начинается  5 или 2?

Comment: массив существует именно в таком виде, в котором он есть сейчас, соответственно двойки не будет, а пятерка просто игнорируется, т.к. в условиях ее нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> использовать минимум всяких if и == использование substr() так же нежелательно

Как-то так что ли?

```
$arr = array('1name','4aaaaa','5smthn','3else');
foreach($arr as $v){
    switch ((int)($v)) {
        case 1: echo "сообщение"; break;
        case 4: echo $v; break;
        case 5: break;
        default: echo "smth else";
    }       
}
```

Comment: но тут же случай с default сработает и на 5 тоже, и выведет smth else дважды?

Comment: @inDee с чего вдруг? написано же `5: break;`. хотя логика тут не особо ясна мне, с таким успехом можно было сделать `case 3 -> smthn else`, раз у вас набор значений фиксированный

Comment: smth else нужно выводить как раз если первая не тройка, не единица, и не четверка, при этом нельзя просто сделать case 5 как одно оставшееся число, в этом и проблема

Comment: не так у меня написано, наоборот надо `case 3: break;` или у вас там нестыковка вопроса и коммента под ним.

Answer (score 0):

А если [так](https://repl.it/@tomasj/noIF)?

```
$arr = array('1name','4aaaaa','5smthn','3else');
$answer = array(1=>'message 1', 4=>'##', 5=>'message 2');
foreach($answer as $key=>$message){
  $item = $arr[array_search($key, $arr)];
  echo $item . ':' . str_replace('##', $item, $message) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Возвращает:

```
1name:message 1
4aaaaa:4aaaaa
5smthn:message 2
```